# SQL Syntax For Right Outer JOIN in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We're having an issue with SQL Server 2012 due to the presence of   `=*`  (RIGHT OUTER JOIN) operator.

Can anyone tell me what is the correct syntax for SQL Server 2012 for the following SQL that worked correctly on SQL Server 2008?

```
  SELECT 
    ProcessCode, 
    ProcessDesc, 
    DisciplineDesc, 
    ValidProcessName .DisciplineCode 
 FROM 
    ValidName, ValidProcessName 
 WHERE
    ValidProcessName.DisciplineCode =* ValidName.DisciplineCode 
 ORDER BY 
    ProcessCode
```

Comment: SELECT Fields FROM tbl1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.field1=tbl2.field2

Comment: `*=` is the ancient (pre SQL-92 standard) notation for `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `=*` is for `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is:

```
SELECT 

   ProcessCode, 
   ProcessDesc, 
   DisciplineDesc, 
   ValidProcessDiscipline.DisciplineCode 

FROM 

   ValidProcess RIGHT OUTER JOIN ValidProcessDiscipline 

ON

   ValidProcessDiscipline.DisciplineCode = ValidProcess.DisciplineCode 

ORDER BY 

   ProcessCode
```

Answer (score 5):

So the first thing to note is that a `RIGHT` join is the same as a `LEFT` join, but with the table orders swapped around.

Personally I never use `RIGHT` joins for this reason and for readability (I read from left-to-right and therefore the query makes more sense to me).

So your query could become:

```
SELECT <missing_alias>.ProcessCode
     , <missing_alias>.ProcessDesc
     , <missing_alias>.DisciplineDesc
     , ValidProcessDiscipline.DisciplineCode
FROM   ValidProcessDiscipline
 LEFT
  JOIN ValidProcess
    ON ValidProcess.DisciplineCode = ValidProcessDiscipline.DisciplineCode
ORDER
    BY ProcessCode
```

> Grab all the `ValidProcessDiscipline` records and any matching `ValidProcess` records.

Of course if you insist on using a `RIGHT` join then:

```
SELECT <missing_alias>.ProcessCode
     , <missing_alias>.ProcessDesc
     , <missing_alias>.DisciplineDesc
     , ValidProcessDiscipline.DisciplineCode
FROM   ValidProcess
 RIGHT
  JOIN ValidProcessDiscipline
    ON ValidProcessDiscipline.DisciplineCode = ValidProcess.DisciplineCode 
ORDER
    BY ProcessCode
```

Comment: I always assumed that people from countries/languages where they read/write from right to left will prefer RIGHT joins due to the same reason :-)

Comment: @dnoeth perhaps... but the rest of the query still reads LTR. "select these columns from this table..."